# How to route traffic from one container to another in docker compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, openvpn

I have this docker compose. I would like to route all traffic from `app` container through `openvpn` container without changing anything in host server. Is it possible?

```
version: '3'

services:
  openvpn:
    image: openvpn
    networks:
      - net

  app:
    image: myapp
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Would you update this post with a working example? having some problems understand your solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it by myself. I can add `myapp` to the same network of `openvpn` by adding a config to `myapp` service.

```
network_mode: "service:openvpn"
```

By this, I cannot expose the port on `myapp` but I can expose ports in openvpn to access `myapp` as they are in the same network